# В каких случаях нужно наследоваться от std :: enable_shared_from_this и зачем это делать?

Tags: c++, boost

В каких случаях нужно наследоваться от std :: enable_shared_from_this и зачем это делать? Увидел в примерах boost asio наследование от enable_shared_from_this, что это дает и почему это необходимо?

Comment: https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1414193955/enable_shared_from_this-overview-examples-and-internals